# Example of physical phenomenon with zero velocity at some point that does not correspond to an extremum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, velocity

For many students (at least mine), the vanishing of the derivative $f$ at some point means that the function is maximal at that point. The cubic function $f(x)=x^3$ shows this is false. Students understand the counter-example during class, but seems to fail to remember it during "real examples".

I wish to find a natural physical situation where:

- an object is travelling along a line, so position can be represented as a function $f(x)$ of a single variable
- The function $f$ is strictly increasing (or monotonic, never mind), but at at least one isolated point, the velocity $f'(x)$ is zero.
- Velocity should be defined on all the motion, except maybe at initial and terminal times. No condition on the acceleration.

This will illustrate situation where the object does not change direction when the velocity vanishes (contrary to the parabolic motion of a projectile subjected to gravity on Earth, for example, where intuitively, to go from moving up to moving down, velocity should cancel).

Comment: I hope the question is focused enough. I am looking for classical, textbookish application of mechanics, so I think it is not too broad. I was hesitating between Maths.SE, MathsEducator.SE and here before posting, so I wouldn't be upset if you think the question is not appropriate here (please comment in that case).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because physics is not an application of mathematics and it does not lend itself to the teaching of mathematical theorems.

Comment: This question (v1) seems like a list question.

Comment: @CuriousOne While I make no comment as to whether or not this question is off-topic, I would point out that physics lends itself beautifully to the teaching of mathematical theorems! I find various vector calculus theorems to be easier to understand when I envision a charge with some electric field lines, etc.

Comment: @DanielSank: Students who are already struggling with remembering to use the second derivative test for maxima are, IMHO, virtually incapable of distinguishing an empirical science (which they are not being taught properly) from the art of manipulating logical propositions (which they also not being taught properly). It took me until my first year in university (and a class in mathematical logic) to fully understand what math is. The lecturer actually went so far to claim that most mathematicians can't tell you what it is that they are actually doing. I can attest that for high school math.

Comment: @Taladris: While my well meaning comments have been deleted, I would urge you NOT to replace proper teaching of math with virtually guaranteed improper teaching of physics in your classroom. It's not going to help your students to understand either subject. Leave the physics to the physics teacher who has at least a fighting chance to teach the subject properly (sadly in the US most can't even do that).

Answer (score 0):

A case of the velocity going to zero while the position is not an extremum would be a car travelling in a constant direction (e.g. eastward), stopping at a stop sign, then resuming an eastward travel.  Of course, the acceleration is not constant, but an $x$ vs $t$ plot would be continuous.

[image]

It would also be a piecewise continuous function, not a simple polynomial.